# Graphics - equation to convert 3d point to 2d projection

Tags: graphics, 3d, 2d

I am a graphics novice, but am playing with HTML5 Canvas, javascript and some shapes and images.
If I have a camera at point C.x,C.y,C.z, and a point at P.x,P.y,P.z, what is the easiest way to convert the point to a 2d point so I can render an image at that point with the correct scaling so my perspective is correct?  I'm after the equations, not a library.

Thanks!

Comment: A camera and a point are not enough, you'll also need a direction for the camera (f.e. a direction vector or a point to look at). Even in this case, there are some open parameters left like FOV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the Perspective Projection and the formula you seek is just the matrix-multiplication found here:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection

Comment: @eznme - great, thanks.  I assume that using javascript I'll need to use the equations.  Does the dx=cos0y.(sin0z... actually mean dx=cos0y*(sin0z...   i.e. does the dot mean multiplied by?

Comment: @John Norris: yes, normal multiplication (not vector/scalar/dot/cross-product in that case). Directly below that where they write `b_x = ...` they omit the point and in the paragraph "Diagram" just below that the "x" also means normal multiplication; i can see how such inconsistency must be confusing (it definitely is to me).

Comment: @John Norris: wow got it working already? very fast. impressive.

Comment: @eznme - well, all down to you pointing me at the right equations!  Coupled with a simple array of objects with xyz and a mousemove event the poc looks good.  Thanks again.

Comment: @eznme - whilst I've got a basic 'world' working, I want the ability to navigate around it and I'm struggling with one aspect; I don't understand the role that the camera orientation plays.  If I want my world to have an x,y,z 'origin', and I always want my camera to be 'pointing' at that origin, what should I set 0x, 0y and 0z to?  Thanks.

Comment: @John Norris: The transformation you have at the moment is equivalent to the "Projection Matrix" and "Divide by w" on this site: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html . Essentially your ModelView matrix is still the Identity-Matrix at the moment.

Comment: @John Norris: The picture is just a visualization of what happens to a single vertex, to program this you can just multiply your vertices by a ModelView matrix that translates and scales your model before multiplying the vertices with the projection-matrix.