# How to map 3D coordinates to 2D plane

Tags: java, c++, opengl, math, 3d

I'm writing a OpenGL application in which there is a rectangle placed on a 3D object. The 3D object can move around and rotate and the rectangle follows these movements.

What I would like to do is to point with the mouse towards the rectangle so that a dot would appear in that point on the rectangle, and I want the point to follow it as the 3D object that "holds" the rectangle moves around.

I know how to find the intersection on a plane, and I know how to find the world coordinates of the contact point. What I need is a way to *convert* the world coordinates to the 2D local coordinate system of the rectangle.

For example, suppose I have the plane positioned like this in the 3D world, with a given orientation (sorry, I can't really draw properly):

[image]

The black point in the center is the origin of the plane, while the blue point is the one I would like to find. The numbers near the points are their world coordinates; in this example the Z axis "comes out" of the screen.

I would like to map the coordinates of the blue point in the local coordinate system of the plane, like this:
[image]

I know that somehow this shouldn't be hard, but I can't find a way at all. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate (language agnostic): [Graphics - equation to convert 3d point to 2d projection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276315/graphics-equation-to-convert-3d-point-to-2d-projection)

Answer (score 0):

You probably already use a transformation matrix to render the rectangle. If you have the 3D position of the point, just transform it with the inverse transformation matrix and you get a 3D position in the rectangle's space. If the local system is aligned with the rectangle, one of the coordinates should always be zero and you can drop it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a particular framework for this application. It is based on OpenGL, but I have very little access to how things are done in the background. I don't manually manipulate tranformation matrices, the framework does it in the background and I can't interfere. For each object I can get their model matrix (computed by the framework), but I can't set my own. I can also convert coordinates from their local coordinate system to world coordinates, but not the opposite. Because of these limitations I was looking for a formula or something like that

Comment: The object's model matrix is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I needed in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472048/projecting-3d-points-to-2d-plane).

Basically the solution for me is to project the point onto the x and y axis of the local coordinate system of the rectangle.

In pseudo code it's like this:

```
// I compute the direction that go from the origin of the rectangle to its x axis, in world coordinates, and take the norm; same thing for the y axis
var xDir = Norm(mRectangle.LocalToWorld([1, 0, 0]) - mRectangle.LocalToWorld([0, 0, 0]));
var yDir = Norm(mRectangle.LocalToWorld([0, 1, 0]) - mRectangle.LocalToWorld([0, 0, 0]));

// I compute the dot product
mLocalPosition.x = Dot(xDir, (contactPoint - mRectangle.LocalToWorld([0, 0, 0])));
mLocalPosition.y = Dot(yDir, (contactPoint - mRectangle.LocalToWorld([0, 0, 0])));

// I can now set the position of the point converting the local coordinates found to world coordinates
mPoint.SetPosition(mRectangle.LocalToWorld([mLocalPosition.x, mLocalPosition.y, 0]));
```