# How to fill a image with pattern (Fabric on shirt)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, canvas, 3d

[image]

1. Let's say I have an image!
2. Now I want to fill that image with below fabric.

[image]

3. And my final image will look like this

[image]

how to do it? so far I was able to change the color of that image but was not able to fill pattern.

Is there any way to do it with PHP, jquery, and javascript.

Thanks in advance!

**Demo link:** https://www.bombayshirts.com/custom/shirt

**I just want to fill a patter in a shirt like shown in the above demo.**

What I had tried is the below, but using the below code, I lose my shirt shape and image will be pixellated.

```js
var img1 = new Image, img2 = new Image, cnt = 2,
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 
img1.onload = img2.onload = function() {if (!--cnt) go()};
img1.src = "https://www.itailor.co.uk/images/product/shirt/it1823-1.png";       // Shirt
img2.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQlu8.png";   // pattern

// MAIN CODE ---
function go() {

  // create a pattern  
  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(img2, "repeat");
  
  // fill canvas with pattern
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // use blending mode multiply
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  
  // draw sofa on top
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, img1.width*.5, img1.height*.5);
  
  // change composition mode
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  
  // draw to cut-out sofa
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, img1.width*.5, img1.height*.5);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: I think you can do it with svg pattern...but it would be much easier to just swap images. If there is some other solution, I would like to see it, sounds very interesting.

Comment: Yes, it's very interesting @maximelian1986

Comment: :-) You want it to follow the logical shape of the sleeves? It is possible (in some browsers) to make some basic pixel displacement based on the luminosity, but that's about all the 2D context will be able to offer you. What you are willing to do implies a 3D model. And to make a pattern in canvas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido, I want to fill the fabric on the shirt as per shown in the above screenshot. I'm ready to use 2D or 3D whatever it is but just want to fill the fabric pattern on the shirt without pixelated.

Comment: As one crazy idea...you can use Unity Web with 3D model made lets say in Blender.  Downside of this plan -> users will need install plugin.

Comment: Thanks for sending @maximelian1986, but I want to integrate into my website. It would be great if you can help me out about the same.

Comment: The demo link is using imagereplacement. So for every pattern they have an identical shirt with a different pattern created and chopped in to pieces (for sleeves, collar and so on). Otherwise it might get pretty complicated . because there are pattern distortions and lighting change. I think it could be done but not copy paste code from stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your note @kodvin, but can you please give me the demo link. It would be really great full to me.

Comment: i mean the demo link that you provided https://www.bombayshirts.com/custom/shirt

Comment: Thanks, @kodvin, But I need a sample code ;)

Comment: If you go through the DOM tree of the Demo link, you'll see they are just placing many images to the single place, which looks like filling the pattern, all they are doing is smart trick.

Comment: This is tagged jquery?!?  why??  If there were no bounty on this, it would be closed as too broad.

Comment: You can use Imagemagick, which can run via PHP from a server. See for example: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20455. I also have a script that uses Imagemagick called outfit. See my scripts at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Can this be done with code? Absolutely.

*Note that StackOverflow is not a coding house. We cannot write all this code for you, so the most that you should anticipate from these answers is a good start in the right direction.*

You asked specifically about PHP and Javascript, but I'll throw HTML in there too. Let's look at each.

**PHP**

Do a quick search for 3D rendering in PHP. You won't find much because there isn't much. Server-side, there are *far* better languages, engines, and libraries that are designed specifically for 3D rendering.

Good alternatives to this are the languages that most game developers use for character modeling and rendering, which often include C++, Java, and Python (this one more so for logic and sometimes movement).

**Javascript / jQuery**

There are some decent javascript gaming engines out there that are able to handle 3D rendering. Note that these are often not meant for character modeling, as they expect most of that work to be done outside of the engine itself. Usually it's the library used in conjunction with WebGL. Here are two popular options:

https://www.babylonjs.com

https://threejs.org

**HTML Canvas**

It's possible here, but more code-intensive than using an engine that's designed for this work.

Here's an example of gaming with HTML: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/gaming/

Here's a cube in HTML5 canvas and WebGL: https://www.webcodegeeks.com/html5/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/

Notice how much code and effort it takes to reproduce a simple cube. You'd need to account for the outside shape of the shirt, the curving of the fabric around those shapes (not just following the edges, but following realistic curves on parts like a bent arm), the impression of depth for parts of the shirt that are nearer and farther, and arcing of the fabric over wrinkles in the shirt. These details would require an IMMENSE amount of coding.

---

### Is it worth your personal time and effort? Probably not.

1. Return on investment for the time spent will be low. You'll spend a *lot* of time and resources getting this to work well.
2. If it's done client-side (html or js), the included code and libraries would be more than clients should have to deal with downloading for anything less than gaming purposes.
3. Running this code every time the fabric is switched would be laborious on the client-side.
4. **There are better options (ones that require less code and less processing power) that accomplish the same goal, such as how Bombay Shirts did it in the demo.**

---

### How does Bombay Shirts do it?

Below is a picture of the inspector opened, looking at the page's resources. In the red box on the left is a list of all the parts of the shirt. One is selected, which you see pictured on the right.

[image: Bombay shirts page resources]

All the components of the shirt pictured are a filetype **.pfs**. PFS files are proprietary to [PhotoFiltre Studio](http://www.photofiltre-studio.com/pf7-en.htm). PhotoFiltre Studio does image editing, but it also helps establish coordinates between elements.

There are about 11 separate images for cuffs, collars, buttons, pockets, and sleeves. What's *interesting* is that the components of the shirt are not 2D in appearance: parts that are not visible in the final render are visible here (e.g. the inside of the sleeve holes, as pictured above). This is because each component of the shirt was likely made with some 3D modeling software.

**The real answer, however, is that Bombay Shirts didn't do this at all.** If you look closely at where the images are coming from, it's a different server than theirs altogether:

```html
<img class="img-fluid" src="https://bombayshirts.picarioxpo.com/collar_prince_charlie_v00.pfs?1=1&amp;width=500&amp;p.tn=BB001A.jpg&amp;p.tr=True" alt="custom shirts" style="z-index: 2;">
```

These images are sourced at picarioxpo.com. This is the website of [Picario](https://www.picario.com/en/home/), a company that specializes in creating customizable 3D product visualizations.

---

### Solutions

**Use Existing Solutions** ← Choose this one!

Bombay Shirts could never have gone with the manual solutions below because there are too many fabrics and options-- it would have taken far too much time. Instead of reinventing the wheel, they opted for Picario's solution. *You could do the same.*

Benefits:

- no hardcore coding & knowledge
- no hardcore photoshopping & skill
- no hardcore 3D modeling & endless exporting
- no client-side processing power or bandwidth used
- fast/easy to implement

A couple options:

[Picario XPO](https://www.picario.com/en/picarioxpo/)

[iDesigniBuy Tailoring Software](https://www.idesignibuy.com/product/tailoring-software/)

**3D Modeling Software**

1. Use a 3D modeling software to create a model of your product. If you have products with visible options, create one model for each component of the shirt. I recommend [Blender](https://www.blender.org) because it's free, fairly high-quality, and well-documented. [Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview) is arguably better, but it isn't free.
2. Save each fabric as a material/texture (I might have the terminology mixed up here), and apply each one to your model.
3. Export the *same* front view of each model/component with the fabric applied (ex: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39022/how-to-save-render).
4. When the user requests your product from the browser, send each finalized component to the browser with the coordinates that tell it where to be to get it to line up with the other components.

**Manually with Code/Photoshop**

Most any other solution will take too much time/knowledge/money-- especially going the route of manually coding this functionality with algorithms. Photoshopping each image would be an intense amount of work with *very* inconsistent results (unless you're a photoshop genius).

---

**Cris Luengo had a great question in the comments:**

> Why a separe image for each component of the shirt? Wouldn’t it be simpler to have a picture for each complete shirt? – Cris Luengo

Response to this:

> @CrisLuengo great question. It's because some shirts have different pockets, buttons, collar styles, etc. You could either have a completely separate model for all of them, or use the same base models and just update components. It's the same reason why we make use of reusable code: lower maintenance.

---

**I realize that this and the other answers are not what you had *hoped* for, but they are certainly sending the consistent message that PHP/JS/HTML are not the right tools for the job.**

Comment: Thanks for sending.

And I agree with what you said. but not I'm able to fill the pattern but its unfortunately pixelated or blur and I lost mt clear shape. You can clearly see the shapes of the shirt in Bombay website.

Please let me know if there are any suggestions for it.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm not sure how the Bombay did it using photo editor from the website. If you have any ideas then please let me know. 
Skpy : Hardik Kalathiya

Comment: Good suggestions but how can I access that model from the website. !!!!

Comment: Why a separe image for each component of the shirt? Wouldn’t it be simpler to have a picture for each complete shirt?

Comment: @CrisLuengo great question. It's because some shirts have different pockets, buttons, collar styles, etc. You could either have a completely separate model for all of them, or use the same base models and just update components. It's the same reason why we make use of reusable code: lower maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the website you give, the work is actually done in the *backend* instead of the frontend, which you can see from the following screenshot by Chrome:

[image]

About what backend does, it is nothing trivial, but some kind of algorithms in Computer Vision. If you do not have any knowledge about this field, you can first read a book like DIP (digital image processing). Then, you can read some papers about this field - the **3D texture synthesis** and so on.

In short, it is no a trivial task that you can done with only JS or PHP. It is some **algorithm works**, not some **programming language works**.

P.S. Note that the direction and the wrinkle of the sleeves. This indicates that it is not simply copy and pasting some texture but rather complex algorithms about **3D** shaping.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Any comments on why voting down...?

Answer (score 3):

The hard part of this problem is getting the flat texture to wrap realistically around the contours of the not-flat shirt.

If you have a 3D model of the shirt, you could apply the texture in the 3d program of your choice and pre-process the results as an image (though it would still require some human attention, since the software isn't going to know for example that the texture should be rotated 90 degrees on the sleeves and collar). You'll also need to get a cleaner, seamless looping image of the texture than what you have.  This appears to be the technique used by the example site you're looking at (they're actually using a stack of separately pre-rendered images of each of the shirt body, collar, sleeves, wrists, and buttons.)

Alternatively, you could hire a photographer to shoot each of your shirts in the same or similar pose, or hire a photoshop expert to do the job manually (this is how lots of catalog work is done.)

Simply filling the 2D area of the shirt with the texture in 2D, as in your attempt in `<canvas>`, will at best give you what looks like a flat piece of fabric cut out into a shirt-like shape. (There's nothing wrong with your code as it stands, it looks pixelated because you've given it a pixelated close-up texture of some fabric weave, not the plaid one shown in the question; but this technique can only give you paper-doll-like results, not the realistic shape you're looking for.)

If your starting point is an arbitrary 2d image of a 3d object, and a 2d image of a not-cleanly-looping texture, and you want to be able to automate estimating the 3d contours of the object based on its 2d representation and put those together on the fly in a realistic-looking way...  well, in these days of machine learning and generative networks and so forth I'm not going to say that's an *impossible* task, but you'd probably be able to earn a PhD or two and start a successful SaaS if you solved it.

Comment: (Actually the more I look at your sample site, I think they didn't even use a 3d program to generate the source images: several of the textures look pretty paper-doll-like, not as bad as if they were fully automated, more like some of their photoshop people are less skilled than others)

Comment: Well, someone did not like your answer alright. But you are absolutely right. OP wants to get a 3D solution from a 2D image. Not even Google can get it right. And when even Google fails..... Although, Photoshop Pattern fill on 3D object manages quite well. Dunno if PS has its own CSS attribute on W3C.

Answer (score 2):

Your innitial image is 3-dimensional. Of course that if you use a pattern as a simple image and repeat it, the shape will disappear and you will get a 2-dimensional image. The pattern you gave contains a curvature as well, which is not helpful. You will need to ensure that your pattern is something that you want to repeat, so from the top of the pattern the valid continuation is the bottom of the pattern upwards and from the left of the pattern a valid continuation is the right of the pattern leftwards. And you should ensure that the patterns you have are two-dimensional, that is, a spread-out shirt would have that pattern.

If you start with these conventions, your first milestone should be the usage of the pattern correctly in 2D. If you have achieved this, you will need to handle the base transformation of the shirt, to know the distance between the eyes of the user and the imaginary points if the shirt has a given shape. Based on that you will be able to calculate the correct colors of each pixel.

You will need to read something about formulas that can help you: [Graphics - equation to convert 3d point to 2d projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276315/graphics-equation-to-convert-3d-point-to-2d-projection)

Comment: Thanks for your note. Is there any demo code that I can check and learn from that ?

Comment: @Mr.HK not that I'm aware of. If I were you, I would study the mathematical background, divide the task into smaller milestones and implement the formulas. In the meantimes probably some problems will arise, like the famous rounding problem, but all these should be resolvable, however, not without efforts.

Comment: Yes correct @lajos Arpad, but I'm a developer and I'm not aware with this.

Comment: @Mr.HK I'm a developer as well and would be comfortable to implement this, it would be quite an interesting challenge. However, if you do not have the necessary experience in mathematics, then you will need to read some articles. The key concept is base transformation. You need to transform your 2D into an imaginary 3D image. The way to do it is to estimate the distance of the human eye from the screen and triangulate the 2D position of each point in your 3D image. However, in order to do it, you need to properly define your 3D image, that is, the imaginary distance of each point from your eye

Comment: @Mr.HK and then use the already existent formulas to convert your real 3D image to a 3D-ish 2D image. It is not an easy task, but it's doable. I have been doing that for quite a while when I was learning how to program. If you can successfully draw 3D images by using these formulas, like cubes and the like, then drawing a T-shirt in a 3D-ish image is not a mistery. Of course, it is a challenge and it is not easy, but it's solvable.